# Laravel where condition from string

Tags: php, laravel, where-clause

I just want to make a where clause from string as my where clause depends upon the other variable. I did like this

```
$where_condition = "post_flight_informations.schedule_year,=,2022";
```

and then applied to query like this

```
->where($where_condition)
```

but it is taking **$where_condition** as a single argument  so i have a `Missing argument 2` error can someone help me on this thank you

Comment: It is the wrong way to pass, you are passing a single sting in where clause actually :)

Answer (score 1):

Well in that case, you should make your variable to be like this :

```
$where_condition = [
    ['post_flight_informations.schedule_year', '=', 2022],
];
```

and the apply your query

```
->where($where_condition)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

On the [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#where-clauses) you should put a 3 arguments in `where` method to query.

In your question you are passing a single argument. This is the correct way to use `where` method to add `where` in to your query.

```
->where("post_flight_informations.schedule_year","=","2022")->get();
```

The first argument is name of the column. Second argument is operator. Third is value to compare in the column value.

Answer (score 0):

`where` condition used two arguments.

```
$where_condition = "post_flight_informations.schedule_year,=,2022";

// Split the condition into an array
$condition_parts = explode(',', $where_condition);

//Pass the parts as individual arguments
$query->where(...$condition_parts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all finally i solved it like this

```
$where_condition = ["post_flight_informations.schedule_year", "=" , $request_year];
```

and

```
->where(...$where_condition)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use whereRaw
like the following example

```
$whereRawStmt = 'post_flight_informations.schedule_year = 2022';
```

then use this variable with

```
->whereRaw($whereRawStmt)
```